# how do I launch an ajax request after the prior one has finished?

Tags: javascript, ajax, synchronization, prototypejs

I need to launch several ajax requests.
For some reasons, I want do this synchronous. That is to say that before launching an ajax request I have to know if the prior request has been finished.

The 'asynchronous : false"  property of prototype's Updater object seems not work.

```
   // A loop to launch one after each other the requests uploading elements of chunk[] 
    for (i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) {
    new Ajax.Updater( 'myId',
        AJAX_SERVER + 'serviceName=' + sServiceName + sServiceParams,
        { 
          evalScripts: true,
          method: 'get',
          asynchronous : false;
         } );
}
```

Comment: 2 questions: which Prototype version and what browser?

Answer (score 4):

As per the [Prototype docs](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/options), `asynchronous` option -

> Determines whether XMLHttpRequest is
>   used asynchronously or not. Since
>   synchronous usage is rather
>   unsettling, and usually bad taste, you
>   should avoid changing this. Seriously.

You can fire an asynchronous ajax request to the server, it will call a callback function set for the `onSuccess`/`onComplete`/`onFailure` handler. In that callback, you can call the next method, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Have it called by the first AJAX request's [`onComplete` or `onSuccess` callbacks](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/options).

Comment: No. The calls take place in a loop.